# What npm modules is '..'?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking for '..' of npm module.
Because I got an error `Cannot find module '..'`  when I executed `ytdl-core`.

[example.js of ytdl-core](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/ffmpeg.js)

I've never seen it before.
How does I look for that module.

By the way, Below attempt failed

```js
[package.json]
  "dependencies": {
~~~
    "..": "^0.0.1"
  }
```

and then `npm install`, I got `Invalid package name "..":`

Comment: `..` is just traversing down a directory, replace with `"ytdl-core": "^2.1.7"` and in code `const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')`

Comment: Thanks to you. I solve this question! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for you attracting hate.
I couldn't be googling for '..'

So I'll give "unuseful" when beginner ask a question.